# how can I show resources title with link?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I'm developing a web system using FullCalendar.

I'm trying to customize that resources title with link as like using eventClick, but that code I customize doesn't work as I expected.

could someone please help to solve this case?

Thank you in advance.

**the original code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <style>
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        #calendar {
            max-width: 900px;
            margin: 40px auto;
        }
    </style>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/core@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-common@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/@fullcalendar/resource-timeline@4.4.0/main.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['resourceTimeline'],
                defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
                },
                resourceLabelText: 'Rooms',
                resources: [
                    {id: 'a', 
                     title: 'room1', 
                     url: 'http://google.com/'
                    },
                ],
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**the code I added referring eventClick**

```
resourceClick: function (info) {
            info.jsResource.preventDefault();

            if (info.resource.url) {
                window.open(info.resource.url);
            }
        },
```

I also tried with the resourceRender like below but it doesn't work...

```
resources: [
    {
     id: 'a',
     title: '<a href="http://google.com/">room1</a>',
    },
],

resourceRender: function (renderInfo,element) {
    element.find('span.fc-title').html(element.find('span.fc-title').text());
}
```

---

my develop enviroment

- HTML 5
- FullCalendar:v4

Comment: There's no such event as `resourceClick`. See the documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc.

Comment: You'd have to handle the [resourceRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resourceRender) event and add a link and the click event to the element yourself.

Comment: Hi ADyson, I will check some document, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution to the problem:

```
resourceRender: function (resourceObj, $th) {
    $th.html(
        $('<a href="http://google.com/">' + resourceObj.title + '</a>')
    );
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For people having this same problem but in React. This was my solution. Based on the answer above

```
resourceLabelContent={(resourceObject) => {
                    return {
                      html:
                        `<a class="c-table__link" href=/users/${resourceObject.resource.id}>` +
                        resourceObject.resource.title +
                        `</a>`,
                    };
                  }}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thank you for participating. I'm seeing your answer in a peer review, please format your code so that it is easily readable (i.e. fix the indentation)